# Hibernate not allowing multiple threads execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, hibernate

I'm using hibernate in my springboot application. I'm trying to execute one api on multithreading. But at one point when hibernate findBy() method is called only 10 threads are able to move after that line of code at a time while I want all the threads to run parallelly.

This is that line of code

```
System.out.println("Step 0 - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
Optional<RuleMaster> master = ruleMasterDao.findByRuleId(id);
System.out.println("Step 1 - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Here when I try to execute multithreading with 20 threads all the requests reach Step - 0 at the same time but only 10 reaches step - 1. Once the whole execution completes and requests start getting final response and finishes execution only then next set of requests reaches step - 1.

Below is the console output of above code.

```
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805814
Step - 0 :1689945805814
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805815
Step - 0 :1689945805814
Step - 0 :1689945805814
Step - 0 :1689945805814
Step - 0 :1689945805814
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 0 :1689945805813
Step - 1 :1689945805868
Step - 1 :1689945805868
Step - 1 :1689945805868
Step - 1 :1689945805868
Step - 1 :1689945805868
Step - 1 :1689945805869
Step - 1 :1689945805869
Step - 1 :1689945805868
Step - 1 :1689945805869
Step - 1 :1689945805869
Final Response At : 1689945810355
Final Response At : 1689945810355
Step - 1 :1689945810402
Step - 1 :1689945810402
Final Response At : 1689945810564
Step - 1 :1689945810574
Final Response At : 1689945810675
Step - 1 :1689945810690
Final Response At : 1689945810706
Step - 1 :1689945810722
Final Response At : 1689945810722
Final Response At : 1689945810722
Step - 1 :1689945810731
Step - 1 :1689945810738
Final Response At : 1689945810738
Step - 1 :1689945810754
Final Response At : 1689945810770
Step - 1 :1689945810770
Final Response At : 1689945810793
Step - 1 :1689945810793
Final Response At : 1689945814180
Final Response At : 1689945814243
Final Response At : 1689945814337
Final Response At : 1689945814352
Final Response At : 1689945814449
Final Response At : 1689945814463
Final Response At : 1689945814574
Final Response At : 1689945814668
Final Response At : 1689945814715
Final Response At : 1689945814746
```

Please help me with this issue. I want all the threads to reach step - 1 parallelly.

Comment: The [HikariCP maximum pool size](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#frequently-used) default is 10. This limits the number of database connections. What happens when you set [application property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.hikari) `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20` ?

Comment: This didn't work. Getting the same results. I'm using C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource with  max pool size = 200

Comment: It is resolved. I had hikariCP config class which wasn't being used but had @Primay defined so I guess it was creating its pool instead of C3P0. After commenting it, The logic works as expected. Thank you